# Set class in a interface list in YML

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

I have an interface with 2 implementations. I need to explicitly set in the configuration file the implementation that I will use. For the moment I get an error *"Reason: The elements [api.services[0].esrigeolocationfinderserviceimpl,api.services[1].peliasgeolocationfinderserviceimpl] were left unbound"* when starting my spring boot app. Here are the classes :

```
public interface MyService {
   // Some methods here
}

 @Data
 @Component
 @NoArgsConstructor
 public class MyFirstServiceImpl implements MyService {

     private String first;
 }

 @Data
 @Component
 @NoArgsConstructor
 public class MySecondServiceImpl implements MyService {
   private String second;
 }

 @Data
 @Configuration
 @EnableConfigurationProperties
 @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="api")
 public class MyConfig {
     @Autowired
     private List<MyService> services;
 }
```

application.yml :

```
 api:
  services[0]: { first: aValue }
  services[1]: { second: anotherValue }
```

Do you know how can we set the values in the interface list ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the annotation in your `@Component` classes `@PropertySource("classpath:api.services[0]")`

Have a look in here: [Configuration properties in spring boot](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot)

Comment: I am not sure I really understood. Though, when adding the PropertySource I get : 
"class path resource [api.services[0]] cannot be opened because it does not exist".
Could you give me more detail about your solution ?